# Why Grid item Material UI v5 is not working correct?

Tags: flexbox, material-ui, grid

I faced with a problem with usage of Grid component from MUI V5. The problem that if write code in sandbox - it's works. I find out that i have to give sx={{'& .MuiGrid-root': { flexGrow: '1' } to my Grid container. But still my items property of xs doesn't works. Any idea what i missed?

```
   <Paper sx={{ padding: 5, height: '100%' }} >
        <Grid container spacing={4} sx={{border:'1px solid red','& .MuiGrid-root':{flexGrow: '1'},}}>
            <Grid item item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={4} sx={{border:'1px solid blue',}}> grid 1</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={2} sx={{border:'1px solid blue',}}> grid 2</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sx={{border:'1px solid blue',}}> grid 3</Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Paper>
```

And the result just disappointment me
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHmHq.png)

Version if MUI : "@mui/material": "^5.8.2",

Comment: As i searching deeper i found line on MUI : " It uses CSS's Flexible Box module for high flexibility". So maybe problem can be here. I use webpack 5. use   { test: /\.scss|\.css$/,use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', "postcss-loader"], }, in my webpackConfig. Maybe  need to fix something here to implement this module. ho idea